# Get information about functions and related symbol in ELF

Tags: c++, c, linux, elf

I want to check function and related symbol (ELF), in C/C++.

I have previously used gdb and then I obtain the information I wanted.

```
gdb ./mybinary
<gdb promt and reading elf..>
(gdb) info functions
0x000000000067a5a0  bfd_true
<etc..>
```

My question is thus how I do to get the same information in my program.

Note: 
I want to be able to go through the functions with related symbols one by one in my program, instead of all at once as with gdb.

Supposed code for the task:

```
int main()
{
   // any code for elf lookup (functions and related symbol) (while loop)
   // result_symbol is a variable with information about function related symbol
   // result_function is a variable with information about function name
   // it should be possible to compare the data with other data
   char function_compare = "system";
   if(!strcmp(result_function, function_compare)
   {
      std::cout << "system() function found in the ELF!" << std::endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: Sounds more like a job for a script using nm or ld to list the symbols and search through them.

Answer (score 0):

Use libbfd:

https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/bfd/

This is the library used by binutils tools to get information about ELF symbols.

Comment: Are there any examples available with bfd, which uses information about the functions in ELF and related symbols?

Comment: Using `libffd` for *anything* is usually a mistake. `libbfd` was written for a single purpose -- as an abstraction layer for the GNU linker. It *somewhat* works for that role, and is exceedingly bad for anything else.

Comment: @EmployedRussian so why is binutils `nm` using it to show information about symbols?

Answer (score -1):

You may also write your own ELF parser.
Note that objects for 32-bit and 64-bit platform are slightly different.

The exported function are listed on the relocation table,
The symbol names are under SHT_SYNSYM/ELF32_Sym, or SHT_SYNSYM/ELF64_Sym respectively.
The relocation addresses are usually under R_386_* on x86, and R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT/R_X86_64_JMP_SLOT on 64-bit object.

ELF is designed to be simple and for your reference, my 32-bit parser is about 350 lines of code, and 64-bit parser is about 320 lines, and they doing much more than just parse the format.

You may find more reference at: [wiki.OSDev.org/ELF](http://wiki.osdev.org/ELF)

I recommend also read the ELF ABI for both x86 and x86_64 provided in the external links.

Comment: "The exported function are listed on the relocation table" -- no, they are not. You mean *symbol* table.

Comment: What might actually be useful is a link to the source code of your ELF parsers.